# Как выбрать из БД значении и поместить их в input type=radio

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin

Как выбрать из БД значении и поместить их в 
Но чтобы одна из была по-умолчанию checked

```
$place=mysql_query("SELECT place FROM place");
        while($pla=mysql_fetch_array($place)){
        echo "".$pla['place']."";
}
```

Если сделать так, то выбрать можно все знач, но надо одну и по-умолч. должна было checked

Вот мой Html код

```
    <div class="radio">
        <div id="vibor">
        <?php
                $place=mysql_query("SELECT place FROM place");
                while($pla=mysql_fetch_array($place)){
                    echo "<label><input type='radio' value=".$pla['id']."/>".$pla['place']."</label>";
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: нужное Вам значение отмечаете checked. Покажите Ваш html, как Вы сами пробовали сделать

Comment: это да, а вытащить из БД категории и в один из них поставить по-умолч  checked никак не выйдет?
Когда я выбираю и хочу убрать галочку то оно неубирается((

Comment: **1** - в запросе Вы не получаете `id`, запрос должен быть `SELECT id, place FROM place`, **2** - в цикле проверяете `$pla['id']` - если оно равно нужному, то в echo "..." пишите `checked`.